# Google AdMob app-ads.txt Configuration issue

Tags: python, django, admob, linode

I'm currently facing an issue with configuring my Django application published in linode server using Nginx. My issue is in the app-ads.txt file for Google AdMob. I have set up a view in my views.py and added the corresponding URL pattern in urls.py as follows:

## views.py

```
@require_GET
def ads_txt(request):
    content = 'google.com, pub-*****************, DIRECT, ************'
    return HttpResponse(content, content_type="text/plain")
```

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ads_txt

urlpatterns = [
    path('app-ads.txt', ads_txt),
]
```

## Problem:

The view works when I access the URL without a trailing slash (https://www.example.com/app-ads.txt), but I encounter a 404 Not Found error when I include the trailing slash (https://www.example.com/app-ads.txt/).

## Question:

Which is the best configuration to my Django application to handle both cases the app-ads.txt URL? is it with or without the backslash as per the documentation without

Additionally, is there anything specific I need to do to ensure that Google's crawler can correctly detect changes to the domain URL?

How do I make sure that google console and app store has the url required for crawling maybe I added in some fields and missed some. Are there specific fields that is requirement to check if they are filled.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I dont usually have any issues like that and I end my paths with a backslash and it seems to work both ways so I would recommend trying that. To make sure that google can crawl your page you will want to make sure to register with Google Search Console and enter your domain as well as your sitemap. Sitemaps are pretty easy to implement with the Django middleware, check it out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/sitemaps/  . One thing to note here is when you generate the database you will generate a Site object which comes with domain example.com, change it for the sitemap.